# Github CICD Polling Time out

Tags: github-actions, cicd

How to increase Github Polling time on CICD?

Here is the error I receive:

cloud.exceptions.PlayTimeout: Polling timeout has been reached for ******. Status remains running. 32 Error: Process completed with exit code 1.